# Don't understand "RSelenium message: javascript error"

Tags: r, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I was running a script for webscraping in RStudio and got the following error:

```
Selenium message:javascript error: this.each is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'xxxxxx', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: JavaScriptError
     Detail: An error occurred while executing user supplied JavaScript.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I don't really understand what the problem is and how I might solve it. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I am still quite new to this, so concrete steps would be very practical for me.
Thank you in advance!

Edit: This is the script I'm using. The Error seems to occur just before "#end of the main loop"

```
library(data.table)   # Required for rbindlist
library(dplyr)        # Required to use the pipes %>% and some table manipulation commands
library(magrittr)     # Required to use the pipes %>%
library(rvest)        # Required for read_html
library(RSelenium)    # Required for webscraping with javascript
library(lubridate)    # Required to collect dates
library(stringr)
library(purrr)


options(stringsAsFactors = F) #needed to prevent errors when merging data frames

#Paste the GoodReads Url
url <- "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1885.Pride_and_Prejudice?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=VkA2NbcGBa&rank=1"

languageOnly = F #If FALSE, "all languages" is chosen

#Set your browser settings
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4585L, browser = "chrome", chromever = "81.0.4044.69")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$setTimeout(type = "implicit", 2000)
remDr$navigate(url)

bookTitle = unlist(remDr$getTitle())
finalData = data.frame()

# Main loop going through the website pages
morePages = T
pageNumber =  1
while(morePages){

  #Select reviews in correct language. 
      #It should also work if you only fill in the numeral language code, and leave the first one empty.

  selectLanguage = if(languageOnly){
    selectLanguage = remDr$findElement("xpath", "//select[@id='language_code']/option[@value='']")
  } else {
    selectLanguage = remDr$findElement("xpath", "//select[@id='language_code']/option[5]")
  }

  selectLanguage$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(3)

  #Expand all reviews
  expandMore <- remDr$findElements("link text", "...more")
  sapply(expandMore, function(x) x$clickElement())

  #Extracting the reviews from the page
  reviews <- remDr$findElements("css selector", "#bookReviews .stacked")
  reviews.html <- lapply(reviews, function(x){x$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]})
  reviews.list <- lapply(reviews.html, function(x){read_html(x) %>% html_text()} )
  reviews.text <- unlist(reviews.list)

  #Some reviews have only rating and no text, so we process them separately
  onlyRating = unlist(map(1:length(reviews.text), function(i) str_detect(reviews.text[i], "^\\\n\\\n")))

  #Full reviews
  if(sum(!onlyRating) > 0){

    filterData = reviews.text[!onlyRating]
    fullReviews = purrr::map_df(seq(1, length(filterData), by=2), function(i){
      review = unlist(strsplit(filterData[i], "\n"))

      data.frame(
        date = mdy(review[2]), #date
        username = str_trim(review[5]), #user
        rating = str_trim(review[9]), #overall
        comment = str_trim(review[12]) #comment
      )
    })

    #Add review text to full reviews
    fullReviews$review = unlist(purrr::map(seq(2, length(filterData), by=2), function(i){
      str_trim(str_remove(filterData[i], "\\s*\\n\\s*\\(less\\)"))
    }))

  } else {
    fullReviews = data.frame()
  }


  #partial reviews (only rating)
  if(sum(onlyRating) > 0){

    filterData = reviews.text[onlyRating]
    partialReviews = purrr::map_df(1:length(filterData), function(i){
      review = unlist(strsplit(filterData[i], "\n"))

      data.frame(
        date = mdy(review[9]), #date
        username = str_trim(review[4]), #user
        rating = str_trim(review[8]), #overall
        comment = "",
        review = ""
      )
    })

  } else {
    partialReviews = data.frame()
  }

  finalData = rbind(finalData, fullReviews, partialReviews)

  #Go to next page if possible
  nextPage = remDr$findElements("xpath", "//a[@class='next_page']")
  if(length(nextPage) > 0){
    message(paste("PAGE", pageNumber, "Processed - Going to next"))
    nextPage[[1]]$clickElement()
    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
    Sys.sleep(2)
  } else {
    message(paste("PAGE", pageNumber, "Processed - Last page"))
    morePages = FALSE
  }

}   
#end of the main loop

#Replace missing ratings by 'not rated'
finalData$rating = ifelse(finalData$rating == "", "not rated", finalData$rating)

#Stop server
rD[["server"]]$stop()

#set directory to where you wish the file to go
#copy your working directory and exchange all backward slashes with forward slashes
getwd()
setwd("C:/Users/ledgreve/Desktop/GoodReads_TextMining-master/Scripts/New Scripts/Test1")

#Write results
write.csv(finalData, paste0(bookTitle, ".csv"), row.names = F)
message("FINISHED!")
```

Comment: LDG if you want concrete steps to fix an error, you need to provide the concrete steps that produced it. How can you expect anyone to help you fix your code if you don't show us the code?

Comment: @AllanCameron I'm sorry, I'm still new to this and didn't think of that. I have edited my question and included my script. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This looks like it might be a library error, as I don't see anything in your code directly calling any javascript, that being said, see if your library implementation has any way to get error details, the stack trace says for more info  "run errorDetails method", i assume that's from the java side of selenium, not your library, but I may be wrong.

Comment: If you restrict xpath to only review more _//*[@id='bookReviews']//*[contains(text(),'...more')]_ does error resolve?

Comment: @ZacharyCraig Hello, thank you for replying! How can I check whether my library implementation has any way to get error details? Just to be sure I updated R and RStudio and re-installed the packages needed for the script, but this did not solve the problem, so there must be something else. I also ran the commands "errorDetails method" and (when that didn't do anything) "errorDetails" in RStudio, but that only gave me `Error: unexpected symbol`.

Comment: @QHarr Hello! How can I do this? How can I restrict the xpath?

Comment: Change this line _expandMore <- remDr$findElements("link text", "...more")_

Comment: @QHarr Hello! I exchanged the line `expandMore <- remDr$findElements("link text", "...more")` for `//*[@id='bookReviews']//*[contains(text(),'...more')]` and got the following error message: `Error: unexpected '/' in:"  #Expand all reviews  /"`.

Comment: @QHarr And then after the line `sapply(expandMore, function(x) x$clickElement())` I got the following error message, namely `Selenium message:No active session with ID 0801f61768300a82e5bc6f4279d5f3d6  Show Traceback   Rerun with Debug  Error:   Summary: NoSuchDriver    Detail: A session is either terminated or not started        Further Details: run errorDetails method `. It did create a file for the scraped reviews, but the file itself was completely empty.

Comment: Sounds like could be a set-up problem. Can you update question with set-up details. Did you check that the actual correct url is navigated to?

Comment: @QHarr What do you mean by updating the question with set-up details? Yes, the correct URL is navigated to, a google chrome window with the correct page opens when I run the script. It goes wrong after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my own update: This issue was resolved after I reinstalled java and installed rjava (https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-05-25-installing-rjava-on-windows-10/installing-rjava-on-windows-10/)